# C# Read the image from database and Save it to another database

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008

Below this code is where i try to retrieve the image to my database and try to save it to another database. In the first image you will see the error that i encountered during the run time when i click that ok button. In the second image you will see that i already inserted the data with my retrieve image but i encountered that error (I see that the image is inserted but i don't know if that is the correct one)

In my employee_product table i have the "Image" column = image datatype
(This table is where i retrieve my image)

In my product_result table I have the same column and same datatype
(This table is where i inserted the retrieved image)

What i want to happen is to retrieve that image and when click the ok button it will save to my database also it will show to my datagridview

```
//My Code for Adding the image to my employee_product
private void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var con = SQLConnection.GetConnection())
        {
            try
            {
                var ms = new MemoryStream();                    
                pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                byte[] PhotoByte = ms.ToArray();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cbox_supplier.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_code.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_item.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_quantity.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_cost.Text))
                {
                    MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Please input the Required Fields", "System Message:", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                }

                else
                {
                    var selectCommand = new SqlCommand("Insert into employee_product (Image, Supplier, Codeitem, Itemdescription, Date, Quantity, Unitcost) Values (@Image, @Supplier, @Codeitem, @Itemdescription, @Date, @Quantity, @Unitcost)", con);
                    selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", PhotoByte);
                    selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Supplier", cbox_supplier.Text);
                    selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Codeitem", txt_code.Text.Trim());
                    selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Itemdescription", txt_item.Text.Trim());
                    selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", date);
                    selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", txt_quantity.Text.Trim());
                    selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Unitcost", txt_cost.Text.Trim());
                    selectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Added successfully", "SIMS", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
                    txt_path.Clear();
                    pictureBox1.Image = null;
                    cbox_supplier.Items.Clear();
                    txt_code.Clear();
                    txt_item.Clear();
                    txt_quantity.Clear();
                    txt_cost.Clear();
                    _view.AddingProduct();

                }
              }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Input image");
            }
        } 

    }

byte[] data;
public void display()
    {
        using (var con = SQLConnection.GetConnection())
        {
            SqlCommand selectTable = new SqlCommand("Select * from product_result ; ", con);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
            sda.SelectCommand = selectTable;
            dbdataset = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dbdataset);
            BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();

            bSource.DataSource = dbdataset;
            _view.ListProduct.DataSource = bSource;
            sda.Update(dbdataset);
        }
    }

private void btn_ok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
        using (var con = SQLConnection.GetConnection())
        {

            var selects = new SqlCommand("Select * from employee_product where Codeitem =@Codeitem ", con);
            selects.Parameters.Add("@Codeitem", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = _view.txt_code.Text;
            SqlDataReader reader;
            reader = selects.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {

                data = (byte[])reader["Image"];


            }                
            reader.Close();
            var selectCommand = new SqlCommand("Insert into product_result (Image, Code, Name, Price, Discount, Quantity) Values (@Image, @Code, @Name, @Price, @Discount, @Quantity)", con);
            selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", data);
            selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code", _view.txt_code.Text);
            selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", _view.txt_name.Text.Trim());
            selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", _view.txt_price.Text.Trim());
            selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Discount", txt_discount.Text.Trim());
            selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", txt_quantity.Text.Trim());
            selectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            var select = new SqlCommand("Update employee_product set quantity = quantity - @Quantity where Codeitem= @Codeitem",con);
            select.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Codeitem", _view.txt_code.Text);
            select.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", txt_quantity.Text);
            select.ExecuteNonQuery();
            this.Close();
            display();
        }
    }
```

[image]

You will see in this picture that image has a code. If user input another code it will get another image
[image]

Comment: I'll try to help, but have a few questions.  Let's start with... why define `ms` and `image` if you never use them?  And what does `this.Close();` do?  Or what is it supposed to do.

Comment: @AgapwIesu. Edited my code. Still getting that error

Comment: Not entirely surprised because I already suspected the error did not come from this code... it is still the same error?

Comment: *side note* you should use `varbinary(max)` instead of `image` for your sql data type where you are storing your image. [`image` will be deprecated in the future](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). I would also recommend you specify the data type in your `insert` statement's parameter.

Comment: The signature the error shows, for the `Image.FromStream` call, is not what you had in this code.  The one in the error is taking multiple parameters.  The one you had in the code only had the Stream.

Comment: @Igor Noted that one Thank you

Comment: @AgapwIesu I edited my code again to be more precise

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you add some logging into your code, so that you can tell exactly where the code is failing.  I wonder if it may be in the binding.  The control may be choking on what it is getting for that image item.

Comment: @AgapwIesu Is there any other way , in retrieving my image to employee_product database to insert it to new one

Comment: I don't see why you would need a different way to retrieve that image and insert it into the new database.  It does not appear that is giving you an error.  If the error you are getting is still the "error in datagridview... Image.FromStream", the error is not happening in moving it to the new database.  The error is happening when the image is being retrieved into the datagridview

Comment: `AddWithValue` is not recommended.  Best to use `Add` and specify your data types.

Comment: @DonBoitnott Noted that thank you

Comment: Given the stack trace on the error you posted, my guess is that what is happening is that you are loading the image from the original `Byte[]`, and then whatever object that is gets disposed and then the `DataGridView` can not display it.  You show a `display` method, but I don't see where your `PictureBox` gets set.  I'd bet your problem is really with that or the grid construction, not the DB interactions.

Comment: @AgapwIesu Image is saving correctly on my product_result database. I suspect that datagridview cannot determine what image he will display

Comment: Yes, Diether.  I think that is it.  When you are dealing with `MemoryStream` objects and `Image` stuff in general, they are very volatile.  If they get disposed, or are owned by a protected object, you'll get mysterious errors like this.  You need to get that image data into something you have 100% control over.

Comment: No, I mean where you would set `pictureBox.Image = [mydata]`.  I don't see that.  I think that whatever object the picturebox is being given will be the problem.

Comment: @DonBoitnott It is very confusing and hard to deal with, In my txt_code.text when input a code there automatically my textbox will suggest a code (That code is already save in database) when i pick something and click the select button, i will get the data of that code (the image will go to picturebox and other data will go textbox) that's the scenario

Comment: Diether.  Exactly.  The image is saving correctly because your code that moves it from one database to the other, as far as I can tell, is ok.  The problem is probably in the datagridview that displays the image in the destination database.

Comment: @DonBoitnott  pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg) is this what you are talking about ? if not , i really don't know man

Comment: @DonBoitnott 2nd scenario, if i click the select button again i would get the data of my code and this is where i inserted it to another database.

Comment: It looks like your data is partially displaying, at least, (maybe the image is even displaying in the original grid? and only failing in the destination grid?).  The way it is displaying, I suspect, is through data-binding.  You do not show the relevant code, and probably would have to show too much for us to see what is failing.  I suspect you really need to learn about data-binding.  Do some self-training on that and specifically on binding images from a database to a datagridview column.  Add logging to pinpoint your error.  Then come back if you still need help.

Comment: @AgapwIesu Thank you for that advise

Comment: @AgapwIesu It's really frustating, I just solved my problem luckily and the problem is "SqlCommand selectTable = new SqlCommand("Select * from product_result ; ", con)" , that ";" in the product result

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide a cell formatting method that puts the data into an image object the data gridview can use.

```
private void dgv_CellFormatting(object sender, 
DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Image")
    {
        if (e.Value != null)
        {
            ... convert byte[] to image...
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate it , i would like to try this

Answer (score 0):

You can save the image of the PictureBox to db like this....

```
MemoryStream getimagestream = new MemoryStream();
pictureBox1.Image.Save(getimagestream, _pb_photo.Image.RawFormat);
byte[] Imagedata = getimagestream.GetBuffer();
```

You can receive the image from db to picture box like this.

```
var ImagedataReceive = (byte[])reader["Image"];
var stream = new MemoryStream(ImagedataReceive);
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
```

Comment: This will not solve the problem.  He has no `Image.FromStream` in this code, so it is definitely **not** what is giving the error.